# How to get the camera functionality in the android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to get the camera functionality in android webview where it has to capture the image. But I am unable to get the camera functionality.

Comment: Please give more details. Are you looking JavaScript solution or Android? You may add javascript or android tag.